# Парсим все элементы с RSS ленты сайта

Tags: php, xml, парсер, rss

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь парсить RSS ленту с сайта.
У меня получается так, что парситься только по одному элементу.
Как в этот код встроить что-то вроде *while* ?

```
$url = 'http://sch1770.mskobr.ru/data/rss/77/news.xml';
$xml = xml_parser_create(); 
xml_parser_set_option($xml, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);  
xml_parse_into_struct($xml, file_get_contents($url), $element, $index); 
xml_parser_free($xml);

echo $element[$index["TITLE"][1]]["value"];
echo $element[$index["DESCRIPTION"][1]]["value"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$url = 'http://sch1770.mskobr.ru/data/rss/77/news.xml';
$xml = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($xml, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
xml_parse_into_struct($xml, file_get_contents($url), $element, $index);
xml_parser_free($xml);

for($i = 0; $i < count($index['TITLE']); $i++) {
  if(array_key_exists($i, $index['TITLE'])) {
    echo $element[$index['TITLE'][$i]]['value'].'<br />';
  }
  if(array_key_exists($i, $index['DESCRIPTION'])) {
    echo $element[$index['DESCRIPTION'][$i]]['value'].'<br />';
  }
}
```